# Write an XML element as <element/> instead of <element></element> if the InnerText is null

Tags: c#, xml

I am writing a c# class to write an XML file that needs to exactly match the structure of an existing XML we use so that some legacy systems dont get confused.

When the InnerText value of an element is null, I need the element markup of the xml element to be like

```
<element/>
```

instead of

```
<element></element>
```

I managed to do it by accident earlier but have not been able to repeat it.
Here is a sample of the method I am using to write the xml file:

```
public bool WriteXML(string path)
    {
        // Create the xml document in memory inc. xml declaration
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDeclaration dec = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);

        // Create the root element
        doc.AppendChild(dec);
        XmlElement rootNode = doc.CreateElement("root");
        doc.AppendChild(rootNode);

        // Create elements at root node
        XmlElement XE_level1 = doc.CreateElement("level1");
        XE_level1.InnerText = "Text";
        rootNode.AppendChild(XE_level1);

        // Create a user data element
        XmlElement XE_level2 = doc.CreateElement("level2");
        XE_level2.InnerText = "Text";
        XE_level1.AppendChild(XE_level2);

        doc.Save(path);
    }
```

Comment: "WriteXML(string): not all code paths return a value"

Comment: sorry. i cut a lot out for the example. the real one has try/catch and returns false if there's an exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `XmlElement` seems to unfold on each call to the set property accessor of  `InnerText`. This code piece works for new `XmlElement`s:

```
if(text != null) {
    myNode.InnerText = text;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I used except:
XmlElement element = doc.CreateElement("element");
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                element.InnerText = text;
            }            
            Node.AppendChild(element);
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As @Binkan Salaryman stated there is no need to set `IsEmpty` explicitly, it is [true by default](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Dom/XmlDocument.cs,fb9ab6648c8bda3e,references). Just don't set `InnerText` when you don't need it. You can write simple extension method if you need this behaviour in many places:

```
public static class XmlUtils
{
    public static void SetInnerText(this XmlElement xmlElement, string text)
    {
        if(text != null)
            xmlElement.InnerText = text;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
// text can be null here, element will still looks like <level2 />
XE_level2.SetInnerText(text);
```

Comment: Have marked @Binkan Salaryman as answer but this is also very useful. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

What you want seems to be XmlElement.IsEmpty (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.isempty(v=vs.110).aspx)

The docs say:

> Returns true if the element is to be serialized in the short tag format "`<item/>`"; false for the long format "`<item></item>`".
>
> When setting this property, if set to true, the children of the element are removed and the element is serialized in the short tag format.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no value for an Element, set the IsEmpty property to true and that should give you the desired output.

```
   public static void WriteXML(string path)
    {
        // Create the xml document in memory inc. xml declaration
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDeclaration dec = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);

        // Create the root element
        doc.AppendChild(dec);
        XmlElement rootNode = doc.CreateElement("root");
        doc.AppendChild(rootNode);

        // Create elements at root node
        XmlElement XE_level1 = doc.CreateElement("level1");
        XE_level1.InnerText = "Text";
        rootNode.AppendChild(XE_level1);

        // Create a user data element

        string s = String.Empty;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            XmlElement XE_level2 = doc.CreateElement("level2");
            XE_level2.IsEmpty = true;
            XE_level1.AppendChild(XE_level2);
        }
        else
        {
            XmlElement XE_level2 = doc.CreateElement("level2");
            XE_level2.InnerText = s;
            XE_level1.AppendChild(XE_level2);
        }



        doc.Save(path);


    }
```